# Json Parse obj without case class ref

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework-2.0, deserialization

I don't really know how to explain what I want to do, so I'll just make an example :

```
case class C1(id: String, name: String, description: String)
case class C2(id: String, status: Boolean)

trait Test[AnyRef] {

  implicit val writesC1 = Json.writes[C1]
  implicit val writesC2 = Json.writes[C2]

  def test(obj:AnyRef) = {
    println(Json.toJson(obj))
  }
}

object OC1 extends Test[C1] {}

object OC2 extends Test[C2] {}

val x = C1(1, "test", "desc test")

C1.test(x) // Here I want my C1 instance to be parsed as Json
```

Comment: I don't understand where there is any JSON in your code (I mean `Strings` containing JSON). Would you like to *serialize* `x` to JSON? (create a `String` from an object)

Comment: @gzm0 There is no Json in my code but I want to produce Json form a case class instance which can either be C1 or C2.

Comment: OK. Do yo get any error? I suppose you are missing the implicit for `toJson` in `Test.test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
trait Test[T] {

  implicit val writesT = Json.writes[T]

  def test(obj: T) {
    println(Json.toJson(obj))
  }
}

object C1 extends Test[C1]

val x = C1(1, "test", "desc test")

OC1.test(x)
```

I unfortunately don't have play installed right now I can't test.

**UPDATE** If the upper doesn't work, this will:

```
trait Test[T] {
  implicit val writesT: Writes[T]
  // ...
}

object OC1 extends Test[C1] {
  implicit val writesT = Json.writes[C1]
}
```

But requires more typing.

Comment: Yes this is the idea! AnyRef is nothing in term of static typing for implicit resolution so you must give a precise type T to be able to use Json.toJson which searches for an implicit Writes[T]

Comment: ok that what I was trying in the beginning, strange I'm getting an error : No unapply function found. I'm going to investigate

Comment: @RochDelsalle `Json.writes` actually calls a macro, so it is potentially an issue that `T` is not fully known from the beginning. Have a look at the update.

Comment: yep its strange even with the override implicit val writesT in OC1 I still get "No unapply function found" in the Test trait

Comment: @RochDelsalle did you make `writesT` abstract?

Comment: @gzm0 no I didn't make it abstract ;)

Comment: Ok it works now I had forgoten something, thank you for your help guys